# HIghlighting new files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We just recently transitioned over to VS 2013 with TFS, and I noticed that the visual Queue for new files in a solution is much smaller then it was in the previous version. You get a tiny little plus sign which is very difficult to see.
Does anybody know if there is a setting to highlight new files within a solution in a more obvious way than the tiny little plus sign?[image: Solution Explorer]

The item above the selected item in the image, is a new file. As you can see, that little plus sign is really tough to notice.

Comment: Was the provided answer useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
Look for the Pending Changes Filter functionality in the Solution Explorer. I am attaching the before and after pictures.

Before applying the filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AA7A.jpg

After applying the filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oalm.jpg

Option 2: Use the Team Explorer - Pending Changes Window.

(I apologize for not posting the images inline. I don't have enough reputation points)